# How to load sjPlot when receiving namespace:insight error?

Tags: r, sjplot

When loading sjPlot, I receive the following error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘sjPlot’:
 object ‘reshape_ci’ is not exported by 'namespace:insight'
```

I read [elsewhere](https://github.com/strengejacke/sjPlot/issues/639) that the insight package might be out of date. So I've tried to update the insight package to no avail. I also tried updating the sjPlot package without success. I did all of these things in combination with restarting a clean RStudio session (closing and re-opening RStudio) and also removed and re-installed sjPlot and insight. I also tried `update.packages()` for both sjPlot and insight.

I'm out of ideas on how to load the sjPlot package at this point. How can I load it?

Comment: I suspect you need to update your installation of all the dependencies of sjPlot.

Comment: We're the installations/updates for `insight` successful, or did they produce errors ("non-zero exit status")? You could check if it is possible to load insight directly ( `library(insight)`). Or simply force the installation of sjPlot with all dependencies `devtools::install_cran("sjPlot", force = TRUE, dependencies = TRUE)`

Comment: @pholzm: The ability to load pkg:insight will not tell you if a new version with the needed function is available. Your last suggestion is the one to go with.

Comment: updating all dependencies of sjPlot did the trick

Comment: @IRTFM good point. Didn't consider this might be an issue after succesfully updating the packages to latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem:

> library("sjPlot")

*Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘sjPlot’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
there is no package called ‘nloptr’*

After many tries I receive a message from R:
*Install package "strengejacke" from GitHub (`devtools::install_github("strengejacke/strengejacke")`) to load all sj-packages at once!*

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33645529)

Answer (score 0):

Simply install `sjPlot` from GitHub by using this line of codes

```
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("strengejacke/sjPlot")
```

In case you receive error message that devtools is not available, you can install `devtools` first using:

```
install.package(devtools)
```